# Output of class function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, class, object-oriented-analysis

I'm working with classes a long time ago but yet I couldn't get one thing that how to OUTPUT from a function/Constructor of like a function. I have seen multiple examples but coulnd't clear the point. Here I'v a simple example of `myFunc` outputting an array, and same function in class, How to output from class like a function.
How to take output from any function of class just like a function?

**myFunc:**

```
function M=myFunc(n)
[M]=[];
i=0;
for ii=1:n
    M(ii)=i;
    %% Counter
    i=i+4;
end
end
```

**MyClass:**

```
    classdef myClass
        properties (Access=private)
            n
            M
            i
        end
        methods
            function obj = myClass(n)
                obj.n = n;
            end
            function myFunc(obj)

                for ii=1:obj.n
                    obj.M(ii)=obj.i;
                    %% Counter
                    obj.i=obj.i+4;
                end
            end
        end
    end

**EDIT 1:**
classdef myClass
    properties (Access=private)
        n
        M
        i
    end
    methods
        function obj = myClass(n)
            obj.n = n;
        end


    function M = myFunc(obj)

            for ii=1:obj.n
                obj.M(ii)=obj.i;
                %% Counter
                obj.i=obj.i+4;
            end
            M = obj.M;
    end
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you add a little example with inputs, call and expected output?

Comment: I'v already inputs and outputs, in Class, `n` is input, and `M` is output

Comment: Do you want The `MyFunc` method for you class to output as the `Myfunc` at the top does? If so it has no output in the classdef, try changing to `function obj = myFunc(obj)`

Comment: and how to access that ? @RTL please clear me.

Comment: not to the above outputting obj.M looks more like what you may want but I do not think this cant be done diectly, would would need to copy obj.M to a variable to output ( as you cant output a field of a structure as a variable

Comment: OK, let suppose I copied to `obj.M` in `J`, now how to call ?

Comment: That's a different question and is covered in the [help documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/methods-defining-operations.html)... a few clues if obj of of type myClass then look at  overloading functions, or possibly look at static methods to call as myClass.myFunc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method works just like a normal function, except that the first input of a non-static method is always expected to be a class instance

You call the method defined as

```
methods
   function [out1, out2] = fcnName(object, in1, in2)
      % do stuff here (assign outputs!)
   end
end
```

like so:

```
[out1, out2] = object.fcnName(in1,in2)
```

or

```
[out1, out2] = fcnName(object,in1,in2)
```

Applied to your example:

```
methods
    function M = myFunc(obj)

            for ii=1:obj.n
                obj.M(ii)=obj.i;
                %% Counter
                obj.i=obj.i+4;
            end
            M = obj.M;
     end
 end
```

you call myFunc as

```
 obj = myClass(3);
 M = myFunc(obj);
```

Comment: I didn't understand this very well, Can U please reuse my code as an example of this ?

Comment: @AhsanAli: I have added your functeion to the answer. Note that you could also either return the modified object (which contains M as a property), or to make the class into a value class, so that the object gets modified in the workspace automatically as it is modified in a method.

Comment: please check the my edited post as per ur Code, hoe I call `myFunc` ?

Comment: `Undefined function or variable 'obj'.` its giving error, I already tried that.

Comment: @AhsanAli: You need to define a class instance first. See my edit.